# Binding to combobox datatemplate from observablecollection within view model

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am trying to have a combobox reflect the changes in the underlying viewmodel when this item updates, I have tried to follow the MVVM approach and using `INotifypropertyChanged` but no matter what I try I am missing something to have this happen.

I am pretty sure I have the `DataContext` correct - the `PropertyChanged` event fires, the collection is populated from my DAL, I have tried specifying the `SourceUpdateTrigger` in the xaml for the combobox - I just cant figure where the break in the wiring is. Your help would be greatly appreciated, happy for direction to usual examples too.

XAML for combobox

```
<ComboBox  ItemsSource="{Binding partsResultsCollection}" x:Name="searchInput" TextBoxBase.TextChanged="searchInput_TextChanged" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="231,88,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="316" Height="25" IsEditable="True">
         <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="PartNO:"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=PartNumber}" Padding="10,0"/>
                    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="DESC:"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Description}" Padding="10,0"/>
                    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="QOH:"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=QtyOnHand}" Padding="10,0"/>
                    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="WHQ:"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=WarehouseQTY}" Padding="10,0"/>
                    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="LastSold:"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=LastSold}" Padding="10,0"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
```

ViewModel Class

```
class PartsResultsVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<PartsResults> _partsResultsCollection;
    private PartsResults _singularPartResult;
    public PartsDAL partsDAL = new PartsDAL();

    public ObservableCollection<PartsResults> partsResultsCollection
    {
        get { return _partsResultsCollection; }
        set {
              if (partsResultsCollection != value)
                _partsResultsCollection = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("partsResultCollection");
         }
    }

    public PartsResults singularPartResult
    {
        get { return _singularPartResult; }
        set {
              if (singularPartResult != value)
            {
                _singularPartResult = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("singularPart");
            }
            _singularPartResult = value; }
    }

    public PartsResultsVM()
    {
        _partsResultsCollection = new ObservableCollection<PartsResults>();
    }

    public void Update(String Query)
    {
        _partsResultsCollection.Clear();

        _partsResultsCollection = partsDAL.getPartListing(Query);
        OnPropertyChanged("Update");
        Debug.WriteLine("partresultcollection contains:" + _partsResultsCollection.Count + " Items");
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
            Debug.WriteLine("PropertyChanged event fired info " + info);
        }
    }
```

The Page containing the combobox

```
public partial class PartsManagement : Page
{
    private String connectionString;
    private PartsResultsVM partsResultsVM;

    public PartsManagement()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        connectionString = @"Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = C:\Register\SourceCode\DataBase\Medicar.mdb";
        partsResultsVM = new PartsResultsVM();
        this.DataContext = partsResultsVM;
    }

    private void searchInput_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        partsResultsVM.Update(searchInput.Text);
    }
}
```

Adding partresult model class

```
public class PartsResults 
{
    private string partNumber; 
    private string description;
    private int qtyOnHand;
    private int warehouseQTY;
    private DateTime lastSupplied;

    public string PartNumber
    {
        get {return partNumber;}
        set 
        { 
            partNumber = value;
            //this.RaisePropertyChanged("Partnumber");          
        }
    }

    public string Description 
    {
        get {return description;}
        set
        {
            description = value;
            //this.RaisePropertyChanged("Description");
        }
    }

    public int QtyOnHand 
    {
        get{return qtyOnHand;}
        set
        {
            qtyOnHand = value;
           // this.RaisePropertyChanged("QtyOnHand");
        }
    }

    public int WarehouseQTY
    {
        get{return warehouseQTY;}
        set
        {
            warehouseQTY = value;
            //this.RaisePropertyChanged("WarehouseQTY");
        }
    }

    public DateTime LastSupplied
    {
        get { return lastSupplied; }
        set
        {
            lastSupplied = value;
           // this.RaisePropertyChanged("LastSupplied");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is it you want to do? Also, can you give information about the PartsResults class?

Comment: When a new item is added to the ObservableCollection, do you want it to be listed in the comboBox or do you want to change the value of the items in the ObservableCollection?

Comment: You need a `SelectedValue` binding in your combobox. There is an example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50638899/how-to-update-combo-box-item-in-wpf. I guess this property would be bound to `singularPartResult'?

Comment: Answering the above - I would like any changes in the Observable collection to be reflected in the combobox - ie the DAL has a search that returns ObservableCollection<PartsResults> from a database - when the Viewmodel.collection changes i would like the combobox bound to those changes but the combobox ends up empty

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand the problem. You need the `ICollectionView` interface to display the data. Here you can find more detailed information.

[CollectionView](https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.collectionview?view=windowsdesktop-6.0)

Apply the following changes in the ViewModel.

```
public ICollectionView partsResultsCollectionView { get; private set; }

public ObservableCollection<PartsResults> partsResultsCollection = new ObservableCollection<PartsResults>();

public PartsResultsVM()
{
    partsResultsCollectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(partsResultsCollection);
    partsResultsCollection.Add(new PartsResults { PartNumber = "PartNumber1", Description = "Description1", LastSold = "LastSold1", QtyOnHand = "QtyOnHand1", WarehouseQTY = "WarehouseQTY1" });
}
```

If you want to make changes in a previously added PartResults element. You should implement INotifyPropertyChanged for each item.

**Note** : I didn't see you add the PartResults class. So I assumed they were all strings. You fix it :)

Answer (score 0):

So it appears that the issue was with the assigning of the results from the DAL here

```
_partsResultsCollection = partsDAL.getPartListing(Query);
```

which does not fire a "ObservableCollection.CollectionChanged Event"

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1.collectionchanged?view=net-6.0

the ObservableCollection bound to the combobox did not notify of changes

when updating the ObservableCollection as follows

```
        results = partsDAL.getPartListing(Query);

        foreach (PartsResults partsResults in results)
        {
            _partsResultsCollection.Add(partsResults);
        }
```

with no other modifications the combobox populated as expected.